# Where is $PATH in a system() declared

Tags: linux, perl, path, sh

I had something weird happen on my computer.
I had gperf installed under /usr/local/bin.
As related to question[I asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185219/how-to-remove-one-version-of-gperf) I had a perl script running on my computer which contain the line system() on gperf with flags something look like

perl file:

```
system("gperf ...") == 0 || die "calling gperf failed: $?";
```

However no matter how hard I try the gperf will not run and out put the failed message

to debug I tried something like

`system("echo \$PATH") == 0 || die "calling gperf failed: $?";`

and found that it does not contain `/usr/local/bin/` where i installed my gperf but only look in `usr/bin` where it was not installed

So the `$PATH` is wrong...
So I googled around and saw `system()` is same as calling /bin/sh inside a file so i tried `/bin/sh` and  `echo $PATH` which found that it contain `/usr/local/bin/` to my disbelieve.
So my question is where is the $PATH for a system() declared? why is it different then the one inside a Bourne shell ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `PATH` used by commands launched via `system` is the same as the one in the perl script, accessible through `$ENV{PATH}`. It's the `PATH` that the perl script inherits from the program that called it, unless you changed it in the script.

What's biting you is probably that you set up your `PATH` in the wrong configuration file. Define it in `~/.profile`, `/etc/profile` or other system-wide file, not in a shell configuration file such as `.bashrc`. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc) for some general information.

If you want to set the path manually inside the perl script, you can use something like

```
$ENV{PATH} = "/usr/local/bin:$ENV{PATH}" unless ":$ENV{PATH}:" =~ m~:/usr/local/bin:~;
```

but this is probably a bad idea: in most cases, your script should not modify the path chosen by the user who runs that script.

If you're having trouble finding the right place to set `PATH` on your system after reading the question I linked to and the questions linked in my answer there, ask on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and be sure to state the details of your operating system (distribution, version, etc.) and how you log in (this is a user question, not a programming question).

Answer (score 0):

On a linux system using BASH as the shell, the PATH is set at login time from the user's .bash_profile file in their home directory.  You can append the /usr/local/bin directory with a line like this at the end of the file:

```
    PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

The other (probably more reliable) way to fix it is to use the absolute path in your system call, like this:

```
    system("/usr/local/bin/gperf")
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend calling `gperf` with an explicit path. What if it's in `/usr/bin` or `~/bin` on some other system? That's exactly what `PATH` is for.